# PHP session not showing a value

Tags: php, html, session

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="pageContainer">
            <form action="second.php" class="formLayout" method="post">
                <div class="formGroup">
                    <label>Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="first_name"><br>
                    <input type="hidden" name="postback" value="true"><br>

                </div>
                <div class="formGroup">
                    <label> Car model:</label>
                    <div class="formElements">
                        <input type="radio" name="model" value="Mustang">Ford Mustang<br>
                        <input type="radio" name="model" value="Subaru">Subaru WRX STI<br>
                        <input type="radio" name="model" value="Corvette">Corvette<br>
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit">
            </form>
            <?php
                if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                    $_SESSION["first_name"] = $_POST["first_name"];
                    $_SESSION["model"] = $_POST["model"];
                }

            ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I set up my code to set the value of the "first_name" and "model" names into my session variables.

When I try to access the values of the stored variables in the submission page of the form:

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>
<html>
    <body>
        <?php
            echo $_SESSION["first_name"];
            echo $_SESSION["model"];
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

I only receive the out of the model value, not the first_name value. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Actually I'd expect the `model` also to be missing. Maybe it's there from a previous test of yours.

Comment: upon submit your code never reaches `if (isset($_POST['submit']))` as you are redirected to `second.php` page. better move this code on top, submit to `self` set session vars and then redirect with `header()` to the second page. or white directly session vars into second.php instead, i.e. move entire `if` into second page..

Comment: Yes, it is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume your first file is called `first.php`. As shown in your `<form>`, the second one is `second.php`.

It seems that you are writing the data into the session in the `first.php` file, but this code will never run because you are submitting your form to `second.php` and not `first.php`!

So, move the code that writes the session variables into `second.php` instead. To test that it really worked, you can create a `third.php` to display them.

*(I'm not sure why see the `model` set, but I guess it's still there from a previous test you did.)*

Comment: Wow, thanks. I was able to get the desired result. If I could ask you a follow up, would I do the same thing if I had the a form on the first page and a second form on the first page? Would I just use the same syntax in the third page which is meant to echo out the output? I'm wondering if the syntax would be a bit different since doing it that way, I am only getting output from the first page (model) and not the output from the second page (first_name).